# $digest() called ten times when using custom filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following angular markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dia in dias">
    <td>{{ dia[0].fecha }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="bloque in bloques">
        <div ng-repeat="hora in dia|soloBloque:bloque|sacarHoras">
            {{hora}}
            <div ng-repeat="evento in dia|soloHora:hora">{{evento.cantidad}} {{ tipoAMedida(evento.tipo) }}</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the line `<div ng-repeat="hora in dia|soloBloque:bloque|sacarHoras">` causes angular to throw the following error:

`0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

if I remove one of the filters, the code works fine. According to what I know, filters are chained properly. What could be causing this?

Here are the filters:

soloBloque:

```
function soloProp(prop) {
    return (function (prop) {
        return function () {
            return function (input, valor) {
                return _.filter(input, function (e) { return e[prop] === valor; });
            }
        }
    } (prop));
}

soloBloque = soloProp('bloque');
soloHora = soloProp('hora');
```

sacarHoras:

```
function sacarHoras () {
    return function (input) {
        return _(input).map('hora').unique();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with lodash's method chaining. `_(input)` caused angular to trip up. I changed `return _(input).map('hora').unique();` to `return _.unique(_.map(input, 'hora'));` in `sacarHoras` and now it's working fine.